# Convert angular view into image for clipboard

Tags: angularjs, html

I would like to render a view from an Angular directive into an image so that a user could right click on it, and copy it to clipboard. Basically I have a directive that compiles information into a nice Bootstrap scaffold with styling and would like to be able to right click, copy to clipboard, and paste into a document as a img type.

Imagine:

```
<div class="fancyCss">
    <MyCustomHeaderDirective2 dataVal="foo"></MyCustomHeaderDirective2>
    <MyCustomBodyDirective2>
       <div class="row">
        <- Content ->
    </MyCustomBodyDirective2>
</div>
```

So On the page they load up the correct 'foo', see the fancy table, right click, and voila, jpg of table in your clipboard. Currently the process is render, get out snipping tool, click and drag,copy, paste.

For clarity: IS this possible? Does a library exist for this? Most importantly, how do I implement this with an angular directive?

Comment: Can you please add your requirement ,your implementation is working or not ?

Comment: @krishnakumarsekar No, I do not have a working implementation.

Comment: I think you already tried ,Now clear after your last update of the question,You want a library to do...,Please find my answer below

Comment: Let me update my clarifation. The reason i brought that up is I was struggling to to integrate with angular.

Comment: Have you seen the examples of the html2canvas github,you have to just call a function html2canvas and to include the script as well ,It will support on any framework(Backbone ,ember ,angular,etc) ,Its a framework independent component,You can call the function in your controller or directive by assigning the function to your scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for pure client side solution:https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Alternatively for more customisable and foolproof solution, you can pass your DOM with inline styling to the server side and render it using phantomJS. Take a snapshot, save it as an image and send back to client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library available

http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

How it works

1. It capturing the html dom content and pasting inside a canvas
2. In Canvas you can convert the content to image format